# return field name and number of rows which meet condition in one sentence

Tags: postgresql, condition, fields

I have a table in postgres with 10 fields, and need to check for certain values in 3 of them, then return the field name which met the condition and the number of rows in each field.

So it's something like:

```
select count(*)
from table
where field1 ilike '%E+%'
OR field2 ilike '%E+%'
OR field3 ilike '%E+%'
```

and then return the field which met the condition AND the number of rows (which I'm not sure how to do it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use conditional aggregation for that:

```
select count(*), 
       count(*) filter (where field1 ilike '%E+%') as field1_matches,
       count(*) filter (where field2 ilike '%E+%') as field2_matches,
       count(*) filter (where field3 ilike '%E+%') as field3_matches
from the_table
where field1 ilike '%E+%'
   OR field2 ilike '%E+%'
   OR field3 ilike '%E+%'
```

Comment: How can I put the count results in a postgres variable so I can then display a message to the user satin field1,field2,field3 etc have issues?

Comment: You do that in your programming language. A select statement can't "display" anything to the user

Comment: excellent, I just found the way to do this, thanks!